# How do I defeat Sentrobes?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In a room in Lanayru Mining Facility, I get attacked by a Sentrobe:

[image]

He shoots missiles at me, as well as two flying bombs.  **Can I defeat it?**  I see a targeting arrow over him, but he's always out of reach.

Right now my strategy is to serpentine, hoping not to get hit as I cross the room.  It's not working out too well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shield bashing the missiles will reflect them back, causing damage.  It takes two reflected missiles to defeat one of these.

Another solution courtesy of [IGN's Wiki guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/Sentrobe):

> Wait for it to fire a missle at you, and then use a shield bash to bounce the missile into its "eye." It will send out 2 "Sentrobe Bombs."  Slash both of them across their respective blue line, with a horizontal or a vertical slash. If not, they will explode. The Sentrobe will fire a missile again. Bounce it back with another shield bash, and it will be defeated.

Answer (score 1):

Another strategy is to target lock and use your sword to defect it back. This is more fun, it's like fighting Ganon in OoT back in the day.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can also just hit the timeshift stone in the room 2 more times if the sentrobe is positioned right. As the room shifts back to the present, the sentrobe will become a mechanical husk and drop, quite possibly onto sand. When it shifts back to the past, much of the sand will be replaced with yawning abysses, and the husk will fall into those before the sentrobe activates.